# "Couldn't get size" error when turning off ubuntu from usb key

Tags: boot, dual-boot

This is a a follow up question from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176134/couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-3-fr/1176163#1176163)

I recently got a new computer and I have been trying to get a dual boot Windows/Ubuntu to work, so I got ubuntu on a usb key( using Rufus as recommended in
the Ubuntu page) and after solving the problem on the previous question, I manage  to get into the try version of Ubuntu, but another problem appeared when I turned off ubuntu ( from the try version, It was a bit late so I decided to install it later the next day). It took a long while ( about 3 min) for the desktop to disappear (in the mean time it was frozen). When if finally disappeared I found this message(which again contains the "Couldn't get size error):
[image]
and it continues:
[image]
This makes me worried about installing it from this key. Should I just try to install it anyways(hopping that is only a problem booting from the USB key)? or this problem could persists in the installed version?

UPDATE: When trying to install it, it doesn't recognize the windows installation and If I choose "do something else" it only recognize my HDD, it doesn't see the SSD where windows is located. It is possible to install ubuntu in the SSD? If not, if I install it on a partition of the HDD, would this allow me to dual boot?

Comment: I suggest that you install Ubuntu anyway. I think that it is a problem specifically when booting from the USB drive. In the installed system you may need the boot option `nomodeset` and later, when running the installed system, install a proprietary nvidia driver to make the graphics card perform well.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks, I just tried that, and It seem that Ubuntu doesn't see one of my drives, I wonder if this is related to the original "couldn't get size" problem (I updated the question with some details).

Comment: Often when Ubuntu doesn't see the Windows partition, the problem is that Windows is hibernated or semi-hibernated. Semi-hibernation is also called Fast Startup and can be turned off in Windows. But it should also work to boot into Windows and **reboot** (not shut down). Beware, installing operating systems is risky, so **backup everything that you cannot afford to lose** before you start on this adventure.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running on your USB pendrive? 18.04.3 or 19.10? If 19.10, please consider, that it is not yet released, and there may be serious bugs, that will be squashed before it will be released.

Comment: @sudodus All the times I tried to install ubuntu was from rebooting from windows. The version that I have tried is 18.04.3 at the moment. Thanks for the advice about installing OSs.

Comment: It seems that Ubuntu has unusual problems with your computer. Anyway, "If not, if I install it on a partition of the HDD, would this allow me to dual boot?": Yes, dual boot can be on the same or on different drives.

Comment: @sudodus Does that mean that I have to setup manually the grub for the dual boot? Normaly ubuntu does automaticly, but in this case, if ubuntu doesn't know about the windows partition It wont do it.

Comment: You might be happy to select drive via some hotkey at boot. Otherwise, yes, you might have to set up grub manually.

Comment: @sudodus Ok, that hotkey idea sounds good to me. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)