# "Couldn't get size: 0x8000..."

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Ubuntu won't install. Have a new HP computer with Win 10. Have formatted the drive to add a partition for Ubuntu 18.04. Used Rufus to get Ubuntu onto a USB Stick. With USB Stick in place, I reboot and get the message: "Couldn't get size: 0x8000...".  Have also tried loading Ubuntu using USB stick using the latest version available of Universal-USB-Installer and got same result.  Have tried to install Ubuntu using this method on a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: nouveau.modeset=0 in GRUB is the key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MODSIGN: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e Couldn't get UEFI db list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203481/modsign-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list)

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered in another post ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176134/couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-from)) although the answer that did get the most votes did not work for me. The problem is a bug in the ubuntu version 18.04.4  [Ubuntu/casper bug #1489855](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1489855). In my specific case I could not install it on a Dell Precison 7920 station. What worked for me was to use an older version of ubuntu 18.04 in particular 18.04.1 and then upgrade to the latest 18.04 LTS. Hope this helps.